# Reducing to one row per duplicate row same table

Tags: php, mysql, comparison

[Table Name - Enrolments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c4KB.png)

```
 +-----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+
 +  unit_id  +  student_number  +  unit_code  +  course_id  +  status_id  + last_modified_date  +
 +-----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+
 +   20102   +    SN0001        +  HP-306.12  +   BPL-12    +  WITHDRAWN  +   2/8/2016 15:08     +
 +-----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+
 +   20102   +    SN0001        +  HP-306.12  +   BMin-12   +  COMPLETED  +   2/8/2016 15:08     +
 +-----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+
 +   20110  +     SN0002        +  AS-105.11  +   BBS-12    +  WITHDRAWN  +   2/9/2016 12:01     +
 +-----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+
 +   20110   +    SN0002        +  AS-105.11  +   BMin-13   +  WITHDRAWN  +   2/9/2016 15:13     +
 +-----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

I've this data as shown in the table-enrolments, there are matching unit_id, student_number

2 conditions i would like to run a sql queries on the table:

a. I would like to remove the 'duplicated' rows and only retain the row that *does not* have status_id widthdrawn.

b. however, if the 2 'duplicated' rows both have withdrawn status_id and i just want to keep one.

The end result should look like the following table screen shot

[Table Name - Newly changed table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqOo8.png)

```
 +-----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+
+  unit_id  +  student_number  +  unit_code  +  course_id  +  status_id  +  last_modified_date  +
+-----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+
+   20102   +    SN0001        +  HP-306.12  +   BMin-12   +  COMPLETED  +   2/8/2016 15:08     +
+-----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+
+   20110   +    SN0002        +  AS-105.11  +   BMin-13   +  WITHDRAWN  +   2/9/2016 15:13     +
+-----------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Anyone can help on this ?

Comment: we help you with code you have written, so far you have none.

Answer (score 0):

## Your solution

Perhaps something like

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY `status_id`) t1 GROUP BY `unit_id`, `student_number`;
```

Be warned, I've not tested this query myself so I cannot guarantee it works, report back if it does not and let me know the error ^_^

Comment: Hmm... the ordering by status id didn't really effect for this statement. It returns the first row of the 2 instead of alphbetical order